# Why does my button control not display in the code behind?

Tags: asp.net, button

I have the following code in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltPost" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and this in my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        BindData();            
    }
}

protected void BindData() {
    str.Append(@"<asp:Button ID=*btnEditReply* runat=*server* CssClass=*button-action m-r-5* Text=*Sửa phản hồi* ValidationGroup=*AddSave*/>");
    ltPost.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',').Replace('*', '"');
}
```

I don't understand this; Why won't the button `btnEditReply` display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a server control, you have to use `Controls.Add()`. Also, you can't add a button to a literal, so it's better to use a Placeholder.

C#:

```
Button editButton = new Button();
editButton.ID = "btnEditReply";
editbutton.Text = "Sửa phản hồi";
// .. etc
placeHolder.Controls.Add(editButton);
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Placeholder id="placeHolder" runat="server" />
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx